# Pink Winter Sleeping Bags

Tags: winter, sleeping-bags, women

Are there any good winter sleeping bags geared towards women who like the color PINK? One that is good for backpacking and for cold (0 degree) temps.

Comment: At enLIGHTend equipment we can make a quilt for you with a pink shell. We don't have a lot of pink fabric but we have some. -Tim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A wonderful woman I know has the Habenera bag by REI ([link](http://www.rei.com/skuimage/828484)).

It's a warm bag. We've taken it backpacking in the snow and on mountains, and she likes it a lot. It's also a high-quality, light-weight bag. And it's pink.

Comment: What is the correct way to link to gear on Great Outdoors? I feel like this will be a problem again in the future.

Comment: I don't know.  In this case the product seems to be discontinued.  I think an argument could be made for closing or even deleting this question since it was specific to a certain time.  (You would not lose any reputation points if this were done because of the age of the post.)

Answer (score 6):

If you can settle on purple [Nunatak](http://www.nunatakusa.com/site07/main_pages/fabrics_nunatak.htm) and [Feather Friends](http://featheredfriends.com/sleeping-bags/sleeping-bags/three-season.html?ff_sleeping_bag_temp=86) have good sleeping bags in those colors. One option could be to get a custom made sleeping bag from the cottage industry. Many will accept custom orders although they may not have something available in pink.